# Can't compare database latitude and longitude with current location

Tags: android, database, location, background-service

So I am trying to get current latitude and longitude and comparing it with the data I stored in my database using cursor...but when I am trying to run this app on my cell then its getting force close after some time..don't know why what the reason is....
Here's the code for getting current location and comparing it with database

```
package com.example.alert;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class service extends Service{

LocationManager lm;

DatabaseHelper db=new DatabaseHelper(this);
List<String> arlist=new ArrayList<String>();


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public void onCreate() {
    LocationManager lm=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    LocationListener ll=new MyLocationListener();
    //lm.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5*60*10000, 0, ll);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Background Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



}

public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}

public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//  Intent myIntent=new Intent(service.this,CurrentLocation.class);
    }





/* Class My Location Listener */
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
{

    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
    {
        if(loc!=null)
        {
            double x;

            SQLiteDatabase y = db.getWritableDatabase();
            String Text = "My current location is: " +"Latitud = " + loc.getLatitude() +"Longitud = " + loc.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),Text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //  String t=loc.getLatitude().toString();
            Cursor cr=null;
            cr=y.rawQuery("SELECT LATITUDE FROM"+ "data",null);
            cr.moveToFirst();
            while(cr.moveToNext()) {

                arlist.add(cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("Latitude")));
                }
            for(int i=0;i<arlist.size();i++){
                if(arlist.get(i)==Double.toString(loc.getLatitude())){
                    Intent myIntent=new Intent(service.this,SilVib.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            }

            /*  cr.moveToFirst();
            while(!cr.isAfterLast()) {
                 al.add(cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(dbAdapter.KEY_NAME))); //add the item
                 cr.moveToNext();
            }*/
        //  lm.addProximityAlert(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 10009,, intent)

            //for loop, alerters retrieving one by one
//      x= calcDistance(loc.getLatitude(),loc.getLongitude(),z,y);
    //      if(x<1){
        //        Intent myIntent = new Intent(ViewAlerters.this,CallMode.class);
          //        startActivity(myIntent);
            }

        }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Gps Disabled - @From :Alert Me",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();


    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Gps Enabled - @From :Alert Me",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    }


/*  public double calcDistance(double latA, double longA, double latB, double longB) {

    double theDistance = (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(latA)) *  Math.sin(Math.toRadians(latB)) + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(latA)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(latB)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(longA - longB)));
    return new Double((Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(theDistance))) * 69.09*1.6093);
}
*/
```

}

Comment: You have to post the logcat output of the crash.

Comment: No error is coming because I can't move my laptop also when through emulator control I am trying to send latitude and longitude..its not doin that....and I already told that when I am trying to run it on cell its getting force closed when I am moving